# How to access process.env variables inside /server/api directory in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, composable

In a Nuxt 3 app, I have created an `/api/` folder inside the `server` folder of Nuxt 3, where I've created a file `posts.ts`. In this file, I'm integrating **Ghost CMS** content API. Since then, I've installed the package and imported into the `post.ts` file, and I'm trying to access the ENV variables through `useRuntimeConfig()`  composable.

While doing so I'm getting the below error. How to fix it?

> [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably ?> not a Nuxt bug. Find out more at `https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#vue-and-nuxt-composables`.
> at Module.useRuntimeConfig (D:\my-project\website\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\nuxt.js:193:27)
> at D:\my-project\website\server\api\posts.ts:5:54

See code below:

```
import GhostContentAPI from '@tryghost/content-api';

const { ghostUrl, ghostKey} = useRuntimeConfig();
export const api = new GhostContentAPI({
  url: ghostUrl,
  key: ghostKey,
  version: 'v5.0'
});
```

I've already tried another approach of using `process.env.GHOST_URL` but that is also coming `undefined`.

```
import GhostContentAPI from '@tryghost/content-api';

export const api = new GhostContentAPI({
  url: process.env.GHOST_URL ?? '',
  key: process.env.GHOST_API_KEY ?? '',
  version: 'v5.0'
});
```

Comment: first check your are loading the env configuration to your main file. require('dotenv').config();

Comment: I'm using Nuxt 3, the `dotenv` should work implicitly here? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I found out that the best way to go about this is to use vite.

In your .env file define your variable as `VITE_GHOST_URL="your URL"`

and in the post.ts file in your server folder get the variable by `const ghostUrl =` ${import.meta.env.VITE_GHOST_URL}`;`
and use the ghostUrl wherever you need the URL in the post.ts file.

This is the best approach but it will only work if your project was set up with vite.